# how to check the condition whether the date exists or not

Tags: sql-server

```
select CAST((CAST(2014 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(9 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(31 AS VARCHAR)) AS DATE)
```

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string is coming.

how to check the condition for above problem...

Answer (score 3):

Use [**ISDATE()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187347.aspx) function to check whether string is a valid date

Comment: Argument data type date is invalid for argument 1 of isdate function. error occured when i used ISDATE() function

Answer (score 0):

Use the query: using ISDate()

```
IF ISDATE((CAST(2014 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(9 AS VARCHAR) + '-' 
    + CAST(31 AS VARCHAR))) = 1
   SELECT CAST(CAST(2014 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(9 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + 
       CAST(31 AS VARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
ELSE
    SELECT NULL
```

Comment: here 30 or 31 are not static values these are dynamically change accordingly

Comment: misunderstood the ques.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTime.. Also for 9th month no 31st

```
IF ISDATE(CAST((CAST(2014 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(9 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(30 AS VARCHAR)) AS DATETIME)) = 1
    PRINT 'VALID'
ELSE
    PRINT 'INVALID';
```